# Google API key for SMTP?

Tags: gmail, swiftmailer

I'm currently working on a SaaS based on Symfony that accesses Gmail via swiftmailer.
Other mail services are working just fine - I've got the problems only with GMail - it prevents my software from logging in.

> Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257

And for my account I did everything (allow less secure apps, disable the captcha, told Google that this login was me, etc.)
Then the mail sending worked for 2 weeks or so and now it's not working anymore again. So maybe now I'd need to switch to a 2 step login or similar but I can't expect users of a SaaS to go through so many troubles.

In short: Is there sth. like an API key that would allow my SaaS to use SMTP?

Comment: Can you post your config.yml and parameters.yml configuration regarding swiftmailer?

Comment: I installed exactly the same configuration on another IP and that's working fine. Maybe Gmail blocked my IP since there were logins for several account from the same IP in a short time - is that possible?